# Writing method that spells word backwords and identifies number of palindromes

Tags: java, string, methods, reverse

I'm new to java and I wrote this method to input a string word and output the word spelled backwards. The intent is to *create* a method and not use an already existing method such as the simple *reverse*. Please help point me in the direction of how to do this to reverse a word. I'm also trying to determine/count if there are palindromes. Please help! I've read other questions and I can't find anything specific enough to my case. I know that my code doesn't run, though I'm unsure how to fix it to get the correct output.

An example would be the word "backwards" to go to "sdrawkcab".

```
  public static int reverseWord(String word) {
    int palindromes = 0;

    for (int i = word.length(); i >= 0; i--) {
        System.out.print(i);
        word.equalsIgnoreCase();
                 if (word.charAt(i)) == index(word.charAt(0 && 1))) {
                     palindromes++
                             System.out.println(palindromes)
                 }

    return i;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems with your code.

1.The prototype of equalsIgnoreCase is

```
public boolean equalsIgnoreCase(String str);
```

So this method expect a String to be passed,but your not not passing anything here.To fix this,pass another string with whom you want to match your **word** like this..

```
   word.equalsIgnoreCase("myAnotherString");
```

2.`word.charAt(i);`
Suppose **word="qwerty"**,so indexing of each character will be like this

```
  /*    q   w   e   r   t   y
        0   1   2   3   4   5  */
```

So when you use `i = word.length();`i will 6 since word is of length 6.So 
    `word.charAt(i)` will search for character at index 6,but since there is not index 6,it will return an exception **ArrayIndexOutOfBound**.To fix this,start `i from word.length()-1`.

3.`if (word.charAt(i));
   This extra " ) ".Remove it`.

Is Index() your own method?.If Yes,then check that also.

Answer (score 0):

the below code prints the reverse of the input string and checks if it is a palindrome

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "dad";
        char temp[] = input.toCharArray();//converting it to a array so that each character can be compared to the original string
        char output[] = new char[temp.length];//taking another array of the same size as the input string
        for (int i = temp.length - 1, j = 0; i >= 0; i--, j++) {//i variable for iterating through the input string and j variable for inserting data into output string.
            System.out.print(temp[i]);//printing each variable of the input string in reverse order.
            output[j] = temp[i];//inserting data into output string
        }
        System.out.println(String.valueOf(output));
        if (String.valueOf(output).equalsIgnoreCase(input)) {//comparing the output string with the input string for palindrome check
            System.out.println("palindrome");
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your question about what is wrong with your code was already answered here is another way you could do it by using some concepts which are somewhat less low level than directly working with character arrays

```
public static boolean printWordAndCheckIfPalindrome(final String word) {
    // Create a StringBuilder which helps when building a string
    final StringBuilder reversedWordBuilder = new StringBuilder("");
    // Get a stream of the character values of the word
    word.chars()
            // Add each character to the beginning of the reversed word,
            // example for "backwards": "b", "ab", "cab", "kcab", ...
            .forEach(characterOfString -> reversedWordBuilder.insert(0, (char) characterOfString));
    // Generate a String out of the contents of the StringBuilder
    final String reversedWord = reversedWordBuilder.toString();
    // print the reversed word
    System.out.println(reversedWord);
    // if the reversed word equals the given word it is a palindrome
    return word.equals(reversedWord);
}
```